# Rails 4 + Jquery Validation + Remote

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm facing a problem here, I have a form created by devise, I assume you guys do know that devise doesn't create a controller file to our model User i.e. I have a form in the views folder **/devise/registration/new.html.erb**, I'm using jQuery validation plugin for client side validation since the gem for that doesn't work, it is totally out of date and no longer has support, it was a bit difficult to get it to work, anyway, I have the view file (form), the `*.js` file with the jquery validation rules and messages, a model called User, What I'm trying to do is the remote method which is one of the jquery validation plugin's features, the only problem is that I don't know how to do that, I've seen some tutorials out there but they're all for rails 3, it is almost totally different, this is the tutorial I'm talking about: http://sleekd.com/tutorials/jquery-validation-in-ruby-on-rails/

How can I do that? Since I don't have access to the users controller, I created a user_controller with some methods, I tried to add this method (found in the url above)

```
def check_email
  @user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])

  respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => !@user }
  end
end
```

Also I created a route to this method, I don't know if I did it properly

This is from tutorial (routes.rb):

```
map.check_email "users/check_email", :controller => "users", :action => "check_email"
map.resources :users
```

This is what I did in my routes.rb (note: I have a controller called user, not users) :

```
resources 'user' do
 get 'check_email', :on => :collection
end
```

I ran rake routes and the route */user/check_email* is there

and finally I put in the jquery rules for the email input:

```
remote: '/user/check_email'
```

It simply doesn't work, it doesn't validate the uniqueness on the client side and the form submit doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong? I'm just trying to add the uniqueness validation on client side.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check in the firebug .. weather email uniqueness call is fired or not(open your firebug, go to console, try typing some random email, you should  see ajax call being fired to your server on every word you type ).

Comment: Also since you are using rails 4, turbolinks might have been enabled and in that case $(document).ready will not work, you will have to use $(document).on("ready page:load", function() {

Comment: Hey guys, thanks to you both, I changed the "$(document).ready" to " $(document).on("ready page:load", function() { " and it is working fine! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using rails 4, turbolinks might have been enabled and in that case `$(document).ready` will not work, you will have to use :

`$(document).on("ready page:load", function() {});`